# C++ variable has initializer but incomplete type?

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile 2 classes in C++ with the following command:

`g++ Cat.cpp Cat_main.cpp -o Cat`

But I receive the following error:

`Cat_main.cpp:10:10: error: variable ‘Cat Joey’ has initializer but incomplete type`

Could someone explain to me what this means? What my files basically do is create a class (`Cat.cpp`) and create an instance (`Cat_main.cpp`). Here is my source code:

**Cat_main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Cat;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Cat Joey("Joey");
    Joey.Meow();

    return 0;
}
```

**Cat.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Cat
{
    public:
        Cat(string str);
    // Variables
        string name;
    // Functions
        void Meow();
};

Cat::Cat(string str)
{
    this->name = str;
}

void Cat::Meow()
{
    cout << "Meow!" << endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: You cannot declare objects for the classes whose definition are not yet visible.

Comment: @Ken: You have to include the header file.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You use a forward declaration when you need a complete type.

You must have a full definition of the class in order to use it.

The usual way to go about this is:

1) create a file `Cat_main.h`

2) move

```
#include <string>

class Cat
{
    public:
        Cat(std::string str);
    // Variables
        std::string name;
    // Functions
        void Meow();
};
```

to `Cat_main.h`. Note that inside the header I removed `using namespace std;` and qualified string with `std::string`.

3) include this file in both `Cat_main.cpp` and `Cat.cpp`:

```
#include "Cat_main.h"
```

Comment: So I can't throw my class definition into a different file?

Comment: @Ken no, that's not what I said. Read the answer again.

Comment: Would I define the functions for the class in the header file too?

Comment: @Ken no necessarily, you can leave the method definitions in the `cpp` file.

Comment: Works! Jesus that was a lot of work for a simple operation. Thanks.

Comment: @Ken it's simple but it makes a big difference. You should read an introductory book to C++ where these concepts are explained in detail, there's much more to it than this.

Answer (score 21):

**Sometimes**, the same error occurs when you `forget to include the corresponding header`.

Answer (score 17):

It's not related to Ken's case directly, but such an error also can occur if you copied ***.h*** file and forgot to change `#ifndef` directive. In this case compiler will just skip definition of the class thinking that it's a duplication.

Comment: Excellent comment, I think it covers the most frequent cause of the problem. This is because copying or renaming header file and forgetting about #ifndef directive is tricky while other answers addressed forgetting to add #include statement which is a trivial mistake.

Comment: I have the same problem in my code, what does it mean to change the `#ifndef` directive. The directive already exists in all the header files.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot define a variable of an incomplete type. You need to bring the whole definition of `Cat` into scope *before* you can create the local variable in `main`. I recommend that you move the definition of the type `Cat` to a header and include it from the translation unit that has `main`.

Comment: So I have to put my `Cat` class in the file with `main`?

Comment: @Ken: no, you have to read an introduction book about C++ where the concept of headers and sources files will be explained.

Comment: @Ken: Create a header file with the definition of the class (and the appropriate guards), then include it both from cat.cpp and cat_main.cpp.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error and hit this page while searching the solution.

With Qt this error can happen if you forget to add the `QT_WRAP_CPP( ... )` step in your build to run meta object compiler (moc). Including the Qt header is not sufficient.